# Glan polarizer, field of view

Tags: physics, light, optical-drive

Consider a Glan polarizer with air between the two prisms. The prism angle is 39° (I mean the angle between the surface where ligh incide and the interface with air) and the indices of refraction for the ordinary and extraordinary light are 1.6584 and 1.4684. How large is the angular field of view of the polarizer (the angle of incidence where the polarizer operates as intended)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about physics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

The field of view as measured from the interface is from arcsin(n<sub>air</sub>/n<sub>1</sub>)=37.10° to arcsin(n<sub>air</sub>/n<sub>2</sub>)=42.94°. So if the prism angles is 39°, the field of view of the polarizer should be 0° to about +/-3°, with a slight asymmetry (and another active region from 76° to 82° on one side, but that's probably not accessible).